# Is PostgreSQL a NoSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, nosql

I am getting confused about PostgreSQL. In some places people are saying it's NoSQL, and in some places people are saying it's *not* NoSQL. I have seen something Postgres Plus which is actual NoSQL.

Can you tell me what is true?

Answer (score 76):

You have been confused my marketing and buzzwords.

“NoSQL” is a buzzword describing a diverse collection of database systems that focus on “semi-structured” data (that do not fit well into a tabular representation), sharding and high concurrency at the expense of transactional integrity and consistency, the latter being among the basic tenets of relational database management systems (RDBMS).

Since SQL is the language normally used to interact with an RDBMS, the term “NoSQL” is used as a name for all these systems. Perhaps the name was also chosen because SQL, being verbose and often hard to understand, evokes negative reactions in many programmers.

Now PostgreSQL, like many other RDBMS, has added support for JSON data, which is the most popular format for semi-structured data commonly stored in NoSQL systems. Now you can say that PostgreSQL supports a certain feature commonly found in NoSQL databases.

Still, SQL is the only way to interact with a PostgreSQL database, so you couldn't call it a NoSQL database and keep a straight face unless you were in marketing.

Postgres Plus is a closed source fork of PostgreSQL, so the same applies to it.

Comment: > _SQL is the only way to interact with a PostgreSQL database_  
...Sort of. [The SQL/JSON path language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) used to query JSON data is technically SQL, but it's quite different from any SQL most people asking this question will be familiar with.

Comment: "you couldn't call it a NoSQL database and keep a straight face unless you were in marketing" - lol. So true.

Answer (score 8):

PostgreSQL is not NoSQL.

PostgreSQL is a classical, relational database server (and syntax) supporting most of the SQL standards.

On a sidenote, I suggest doing some research into the differences and advantages. They both have a solid place and time.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL prides itself in standards compliance. Its SQL implementation strongly conforms to the ANSI-SQL:2008 standard. It has full support for subqueries (including subselects in the FROM clause), read-committed and serializable transaction isolation levels. And while PostgreSQL has a fully relational system catalog which itself supports multiple schemas per database, its catalog is also accessible through the Information Schema as defined in the SQL standard.

[Source](https://www.postgresql.org/about/)